# What is the difference in structure for nested vs. compound conditional statements?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, code-coverage

I can't quite remember how nesting conditions affects the difficulty of testing for code coverage.

I have a condition in my code that can be written in one of two ways. The first would be:

```
if A && B && C && D:
    // condition satisfied
```

The second way would be:

```
if A:
    if B:
        if C:
            if D:
                // condition satisfied
```

Is there a noteworthy difference here regarding testing for code coverage?

I'm going to write a helper function so that my actual code looks like:

```
if condition_met():
    // condition satisfied, do stuff
```

But I'll still have to unit test the `conditions_met()` function.

Answer (score 0):

For some people coverage is simply "what the tool we are using is reporting as coverage", but if that is what you are looking for, you would first have to explain what kind of coverage the tool you are using is reporting.

Assuming that the language you are using has short-cut evaluation of conditional expressions, the two different ways of writing have the same meaning.  Therefore, for the same test suite the statement coverage, branch coverage, condition coverage etc. would be the same.  If you look at some atypical kinds of coverage (line coverage for example), there could be differences.

If your intention is to test your code thoroughly, you should come up with the same set of tests, no matter which of the two ways you use to write your code.  Then, however, you should not focus on coverage alone: The expressions in your code would have to be exercised in various ways, testing for boundary cases.  Data flow relations between producers and consumers should be taken into account, and many things more...